# Exchange 2007 move mailbox database - how long should it take?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

EDIT:  This question is really OT...it deals in way too many abstractions...lesson learned over my years here.

If I use the GUI to move the mailbox database from a locally attached drive to another locally attached drive, will it basically take as long as a file copy would?

I tested a file copy of a similar size file and it appears to take around 1 hour.  Can I expect the same for the Move Mailbox Database command or am I looking at hours upon hours to make this happen?

The server is an IBM x3650 dual quad core with 12GB of RAM, RAID 10 array with 6 15k SAS drives.  Average copy speeds of large files is anywhere from 65 to 80MB/sec.

A 200GB file takes roughly 1 hour to copy from partition to partition.  I'm looking to copy an .EDB file of around 260GB using the Move Database command.

Comment: How long is a piece of string?  In my experience it takes longer, but how much longer is really variable - hardware specs, database fragmentation, available resources, etc.  Maybe someone else has a better answer, but I always say "it'll take as long as it takes," and budget the largest possible window I can get away with.

Comment: I would say it typically takes about the same to double the amount of time to copy a test file. But, without knowing anything about the system there's really no good answer.

Comment: Voting to close my own question.  This isn't a good format for an SF question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will take longer then a file copy. How much longer depends on 100 factors none of us can predict.  If you need to predict down-time then I would double your file-copy est. based on 260GB and then add 30-min as a safe real-world bet.  If you needed to be conservative, triple or quadruple the est.

Comment: Thanks.  The basic answer is "who knows, it's unique each time and for each environment" I guess.

Answer (score 0):

My Case:
Server HP Proliant DL360 (16GB RAM, Dual core)
EDB file of around 420GB
RAID 1
Took around one hour.